# How to perform the expansion files to upload an apk to the play store using ionic?

Tags: ionic-framework, google-play, store

I've only found a blog that explains how to upload it, but it's old and the tools it uses seem to no longer work.

Comment: Clarify your question since its unclear.

Comment: what are the steps to create expansion files in ionic, in order to upload them to the play store

Comment: Do you mean to sign the files and verifiy them? I didn't hete expansion except in history lessons.